# Picard group of double "line"

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Are there any nice descriptions of the Picard group of a non-reduced double structure on $\mathbb{P}^1?$ In particular, I'm looking for a description that makes clear the difference between the Picard group of the double line $x^2=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ (in my mind the Picard group should be zero-dimensional, since the curve is cut out by a quadratic equation and thus "genus zero") and the Picard group of the double structure $f(x,y,z)^2=0,$ where $f$ is a smooth conic (which should be three dimensional, since the curve is genus three).

Comment: Which definition of the Jacobian you are using?

Comment: @Sasha I have changed my question to ask about the Picard group of invertible sheaves.

Comment: Have you read the Bayer-Eisenbud paper on ribbons over $\mathbb P^1$? https://www.math.columbia.edu/~bayer/papers/Ribbons_BE95.pdf The Picard group is computed in section 4; its dimension is equal to the genus of the ribbon, which is determined by the degree of the conormal bundle of the underlying $\mathbb P^1$ inside the ribbon. It should be easy to extract the double line and the double conic from the more general discussion. I would suggest starting with Section 2 where they specialize to $\mathbb P^1$, and refer back to the more general results of Section 1 just as needed.

Comment: @TabesBridges THANK YOU! That paper looks very helpful.

Comment: Great! I will post the statement as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ denote the ground field. The paper [https://www.math.columbia.edu/~bayer/papers/Ribbons_BE95.pdf](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ebayer/papers/Ribbons_BE95.pdf) of Bayer-Eisenbud studies the geometry of ribbons/double structures on $\mathbb P^1$; concretely, these are non-reduced scheme structures $C$ on $D=\mathbb P^1$ such that the ideal $\mathcal I$ of $D$ inside $C$ satisfies $\mathcal I^2 = 0$. The **genus** of this scheme is
$$
g = g(C) = 1 - \chi(C) = 1 - h^0(\mathcal O_C) + h^1(\mathcal O_C),
$$

and according to Prop. 4.1, $\operatorname{Pic}(C) \cong k^g \times \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be a variety and $Y$ a multiple structure on $X$. Then, you have an exact sequence, $0\to I\to O_Y\to O_X\to 0$. If $I^2=0$, one has an exact sequence, $0\to I\to O_Y^*\to O_X^*\to 0$, where the first map is $t\mapsto 1+t$. If $X$ is projective, one has $H^0(O_X^*)=k^*$ and then, one has long exact sequence $0\to H^1(I)\to \operatorname{Pic} Y\to \operatorname{Pic} X\to H^2(I)$.

In your case of curves, $H^2(I)=0$ and the rest of the calculations are straightforward.

Comment: Thank you, @Mohan. I accepted the other answer since the paper linked gave this information, in addition to other useful results, but I appreciate your answer as well.